# How to make color keep filling and walking from point to the same point in circle

Tags: flutter, dart

How to make the red color keep filling and walking  from point to the same point in circle like following

[image]

let's say A is the starting point, red color keep filling and walking till it complete the circle in animation

Comment: option 1: (simple)  i think you can use CircularProgressIndicator, then set the value count up.
option 2: Use Custom Painter to draw arc, and mix with animation

Comment: thanks for response , if you have example i would be most thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TweenAnimationBuilder` and `CircularProgressIndicator` for achieving this.

```
TweenAnimationBuilder(
        tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1),
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
        builder: (BuildContext context, double value, _) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator(
            value: value,
            color: Colors.red,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          );
        },
      ),
```

Comment: thank you so mush this very useful answer .. you hit exactly what i want

Answer (score 1):

If you need to respond to a value change, to follow some progress, then you can use `AnimatedBuilder`. The animation you supply to it makes sure that it will be rebuilt more frequently, just as needed.

Example:

```dart
TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
  tween: Tween(begin: 0, end: 1),
  duration: Duration(seconds: 25),
  builder: (context, value, _) => CircularProgressIndicator(value: value),
),
```

This is the simplest way by far. You create a tween animation that goes from zero to one, give it a duration and use it to build the progress indicator.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the Syncfusion library, syncfusion_flutter_gauges: ^20.2.49, in the next link https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_gauges.

I have seen, a pretty radial sliders, i'm sure, that the libraries of Syncfusion are easy to learn, so, you can check and for the displacement of the bar you can use the widget `AnimatedContainer()`, and assign a variable for the pointer, then on SetState, set for the 100% and you have a simple animation of the gauge.
[image]

See more of radial sliders https://flutter.syncfusion.com/#/radial-slider/customization/thumb